# how to add an empty row in a IQueryable?

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-sql, repeater

If you had a filled **IQueryable** variable.

How would you add a new empty entry in the end of that list?

Here is what I have to do:

1. if there is 2 entry, add 3 empty entry
2. if there is 0 entry, add 5 empty entry
3. if there is 5 entry, add 5 empty entry

You can now see the pattern and it's for a **repeater** in **asp.net**.

Should I simply create a **generic list**(.toList()) and use the **add** functionality or is there any better way to do this?

Comment: @Fredou: Just in case you're not looking at comments - I've edited my answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you're happy to convert it to `IEnumerable<T>` you can use

```
query.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(new SomeRow(), 5)
     .Take(5);
```

Note that that will add the *same* extra row 5 times (and then cut the total down to 5). That won't work if you need to then be able to edit the rows; to do that, you'd want something like:

```
query.AsEnumerable()
     .Concat(Enumerable.Range(1, 5).
                       .Select(ignored => new SomeRow())
     .Take(5);
```

(I don't *think* there's a simpler way of calling the same function `n` times, but I could be wrong.)

EDIT: I've added the call to `AsEnumerable()` on the basis of comments. Basically calling `AsEnumerable` means "I've finished the SQL bit; do the rest in-process."

Comment: DAMNIT SKEET!  Faster and with code!  I was gonna pop open LINQpad and edit my answer, but forget it now!

Comment: in the end, I used toList because the concat solution gave me this error: "Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementation of query operators except the Contains() operator." right after I do anything with the IEnumerable variable

Comment: I should have specified linq-to-sql, not linq in the tag, sorry

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'd ToList it and use the Length property to determine what to do next.

But, if you're wanting not to do that, you could do a Union on an IEnumerable with five empty entries and then do a Take(5) on the result.  Seems kind of redundant and not any shorter, tho.